# How to rotate dojox gfx shape at new position?

Tags: javascript, svg, dojo, gfx

How to rotate a dojox gfx at a new position?

The shape is moveable and has to be rotated and scaled at the new position. For demonstration i have used the [Butterly Demo from dojox gfx](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/butterfly/demo.html). See [this example at jsfiddle for the moveable butterfly](http://jsfiddle.net/mbecker/G8f7g/).

How is it possible to rotate and scale the shape at the new position and the new center?

Thanks in advance,

mbecker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ta65D/) and added two instances of `dijit/form/NumberSpinner` (translateX & translateY) to move the butterfly thanks to modified `updateMatrix` function:

```
var updateMatrix = function() {
    var translateX = xSpinner.get("value");
    var translateY = ySpinner.get("value");

    var centerX = 210 + translateX;
    var centerY = 170 + translateY;

    if(g) {
        g.setTransform([
            m.rotategAt(rotation, centerX, centerY), 
            m.scaleAt(scaling, centerX, centerY), 
            m.translate(translateX, translateY)
        ]);
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** To add mouse DnD support add the following code to the aforementioned:

```
var moveable = new Moveable(g);   // require("dojox/gfx/Moveable")
moveable.onMoved = function(mover, shift) {
    xSpinner.set("value", xSpinner.get("value") + shift.dx);
    ySpinner.set("value", ySpinner.get("value") + shift.dy);
}
```

Of course, you do not have to use `NumberSpinner`, but since I put it there before it gives you a nice feedback what is going on behind the scenes. See it at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ta65D/.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. The butterfly shape is moveable with the mouse (press and hold on the butterfly to move it). My intent is to move the shape and then to rotate it.

Comment: Here you go, check the answer above and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ta65D/).